# How do I use GQL to select a group that look like this Key('Group', '1779_1528')

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql, gqlquery

How do I use GQL to select a group that look like this Key('Group', '1779_1528').

i tried:

```
Select * from User where group = '1779_1528'   
Select * from User where group = Key('Group', '5335_5556')
Select * from User where group HAS ANCESTOR KEY('Group', '5335_5556')
```

got this error:

```
'Select * from User where group = '1779_1528' LIMIT 50': Encountered "group" at line 1, column 26. Was expecting one of: <UNQUOTED_NAME> ... <QUOTED_NAME> ... <NAME_BINDING_SITE> ... <POSITION_BINDING_SITE> ... <SINGLE_QUOTE_STRING> ... <DOUBLE_QUOTE_STRING> ... <INTEGER> ... <DOUBLE> ... "true" ... "false" ... "null" ...
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please reformat your question with code blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative is to use filer to show the data you want

[image]